# panels: "no markup at all" as default

Tags: panels, theming

Is there a way to set "no markup at all" for all new panel displays and panes as default? Or disable the other styles, like "rounded" etc, at all?

Comment: Why dont you just override the templates. http://www.fractured-state.com/2011/10/drupal-7-panel-pane-theming-suggestions/

Comment: I'd like to keep the possibility to use the other styles. But the majority of panes is displayed naked and my site builders have to remember to set the "no markup" style every time. It's just a convenience-thing. Overriding all of them won't work with future styles and is redundant too.